# SCSS: How can import a Google Font inside a SCSS file?

Tags: css, sass, font-face, google-font-api

I'm trying to import a Google Font inside the main.scss file, but following code didn't work:

```
@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700");
```

Is there a way to do that? I looking for this question in stackoverflow, but I don't find a concrete answer...

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of using `url()`, try the below:

`@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700';`

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax for importing Google Fonts into Sass:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya + Sans + SC:wght@400;500;800');
```

Answer (score 1):

Right know, using [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) and [Dart Sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass), both work. I prefer the Sass-*way*, just saying. So, with the new Google Fonts’ syntax:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap");
```

or

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap";
```

give the same, exact result compiled from Sass to CSS. Then, if you add one of these in a `.scss` file, you don’t have to worry at all.

Answer (score 0):

Another example from my case, for multiple import:

**CSS:**
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,300,400|Roboto+Condensed:300,700&display=swap');

**SCSS:**
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,300,400|Roboto+Condensed:300,700&display=swap';